# Why does scale_linetype_manual() subtly change the linetype aesthetic?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to manually specify the linetypes for a fixed ordering of factors (so changing the underlying factor ordering is not an option).

```
library(ggplot2)

df = data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 3),
                y = c(runif(10), runif(10), runif(10)), 
                z = c(rep("a", 10), rep("b", 10), rep("c", 10)))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, linetype = z)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, linetype = z)) + 
           geom_line() +      
           scale_linetype_manual(values = c("solid", "dotted", "dashed"))
```

[image]

These are not the same.

1. Why not?
2. How do I make them the same?

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: aarch64-apple-darwin20 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.3.5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is that the three linetypes you have chosen are *not* the default line types. The linetype palette is generated by `scales::linetype_palette`. The first 3 values are:

```r
scales::linetype_pal()(3)
#> [1] "solid" "22"    "42"
```

So you can replicate the default by doing:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, linetype = z)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = scales::linetype_pal()(3))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I even do not see the difference clearly. Could you please check my answer and tell me if I am correct or not . Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae your two plots are the same because they are both using the default linetype palette. Your call to `scale_shape_manual` doesn't do anything because there is no shape aesthetic in the plot.

Comment: Why, when we look at the linetype in the chart created with the OP's two examples, do we see the same "solid", "22", and "42" linetype values, when those don't plot the same way?  `g <- ggplot_build(EITHER PLOT); g.plot$data[[1]]`

Comment: @AllanCameron any idea what is/was the rationale for the linetype palettes differing?

Comment: @JonSpring we don't. When you do `g <- ggplot_build({{plot with linetype manual}}); g$data$linetype` is populated by "solid", "dotted", "dashed"

Comment: @nulptr differing from what? The linetype palette was presumably created to provide an aesthetically pleasing and clearly contrasting set of line types. There are 13 possible linetypes in that palette (and a whole lot more possible dotted and dashed lines if you care to define them). I guess you mean why are the linetype names "dotted" and "dashed" not used for the first two entries in the linetype palette? I can't answer that for sure, but my guess is that they are slightly less visually appealing and show a bit less detail because their spacing is a bit wider.

Comment: @AllanCameron I suppose I more wonder why the hex values chosen for the documented linetype names used by `scale_linetype_manual()` are not the same as the defaults, given that the defaults are, as you note, more visually appealing.